# How Do I Create a 32-bit Tray Icon With Transparency (using GDI)?

Tags: winapi, gdi, system-tray, trayicon

I'm trying to create an icon that displays a piece of text in the system tray. (Obviously, it won't be longer than a couple of characters.)

So far I've tried:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>

static HICON CreateIcon(LPCTSTR txt) {
    HICON hIcon = NULL;
    HDC hDC = NULL; {
        HDC hDCScreen = GetDC(NULL);
        if (hDCScreen != NULL) {
            __try { hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCScreen); }
            __finally { ReleaseDC(NULL, hDCScreen); }
        }
    }
    if (hDC != NULL) {
        __try {
            HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&ncm.lfMessageFont);
            if (hFont != NULL) {
                __try { SelectFont(hDC, hFont); }
                __finally { DeleteFont(hFont); }
            }
            int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
                height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON);
            HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);
            if (hBmp != NULL) {
                __try {
                    HBITMAP hMonoBmp =
                        CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);
                    if (hMonoBmp != NULL) {
                        __try {
                            RECT rect = { 0, 0, width, height };
                            HGDIOBJ prev = SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
                            __try {
                                SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
                                SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                                ICONINFO ii = { TRUE, 0, 0, hMonoBmp, hBmp };
                                int textHeight =
                                    DrawText(hDC, txt, _tcslen(txt), &rect, 0);
                                if (textHeight != 0) {
                                    hIcon = CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
                                }
                            } __finally { SelectObject(hDC, prev); }
                        } __finally { DeleteObject(hMonoBmp); }
                    }
                } __finally { DeleteObject(hBmp); }
            }
        } __finally { DeleteDC(hDC); }
    }
    return hIcon;
}
```

with this code:

```
static void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[]) {
    HICON hIcon = CreateIcon(_T("Hi"));
    if (hIcon != NULL) {
        __try {
            NOTIFYICONDATA nid = { sizeof(nid) };
            nid.hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
            BOOL success = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &nid);
            if (success) {
                nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON;
                nid.hIcon = hIcon;
                success = Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &nid);
            }
        } __finally { DestroyIcon(hIcon); }
    }
}
```

but all I get is a monochrome bitmap that says `Hi` in white text on a black background. (If I change the `RGB(255, 255, 255)` even slightly, say to `RGB(255, 255, 254)`, it becomes black, so it's monochrome.)

Any ideas?

(*Note: I'm **not** looking for MFC, ATL, or any other library solutions, just Win32/GDI calls.)

---

**Edit:**

Here's what it looks like currently:

[image]

Comment: Note that it's not called the "system tray", and it has never been called the "system tray". It's the taskbar **notification area**.

Comment: @Cody: Yeah, [why use two syllables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162613) when nine will do?

Comment: Unfortunately, in English, the number of syllables and convenience are not the primary factors in determining the correctness of a phrase. That area is called the notification area. [Raymond Chen's blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx) is the customary reference. Have you ever wondered why the relevant functions refer to "notify icons"? Yeah, you found a knowledge base article with an inaccurate title. A lot of those exist; there are some with simply incorrect information, especially when it comes to articles about VB.

Comment: @Cody: The third-to-last line in the blog post sums up my feelings exactly. ;)

Comment: @Cody: You're welcome. FYI, though, AFAIK the tray is not a person who can be insulted, nor am I a thing... then again, you can never tell robots from humans these days, so I guess it would be natural for you to confuse me for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly, a partially transparent icon (which I think is what want) has a monochrome bitmap for its mask. This mask happens to be ignored but you still have to supply it. You aren't creating a monochrome bitmap, you appear to be creating a 32bpp bitmap. I also don't see anywhere where you initialise the alpha values for you main bitmap so that the areas which you don't write to are transparent.

An example with code is provided here: [How To Create an Alpha Blended Cursor or Icon in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318876)

Comment: @David: By transparency yeah, I meant alpha transparency, not the traditional pink-mask-style transparency. I'm confused on how to actually code it though... all this mess with compatible bitmaps and DIBs how they're normally monochrome unless you use a memory DC (in which case it's supposed to be color, except that it doesn't seem to be) just really confuses me... do you happen to know of any examples I could follow? Also, I didn't initialize alpha values anywhere, that's true, but I'm not sure how that makes a difference because I'm having a problem with the text, not just the background.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm tied up right now so perhaps someone else can give you more detailed help, but I suspect I've highlighted at least two problems with your current code.

Comment: @David: Okay thanks, I'll try setting the alpha bits. (I'm not sure if it'll work if the bitmap is monochrome -- hope I don't overrun some buffer lol -- but I'll try, thanks.)

Comment: Only the main bitmap has alpha values. The mask is ignored but you still have to supply it. What's important is that it has 1 bit of colour per pixel, i.e. monochrome. Its contents are irrelevant.

Comment: @David: Oh what, really?! I had no idea it's ignored... haha thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @David: Thanks a lot, that information really helped! The problem also turned out to be the fact that I was using `CreateCompatibleBitmap` for the mask; I used `CreateBitmap` and it worked pretty well. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @David: Okay, so apparently it still doesn't work: When I set the bitmap's bits to `0x00000000`, all I get is a black background with my text over it (whose color I now managed to control). If I set it to `0x01000000`, it suddenly jumps to almost-complete transparency (which is what I want for the background), but the text no longer appears. If I set it to `0xFF000000` then the background becomes black again, but now the text becomes white. What's going on? D:

Comment: @Mehrdad Are you sure you have created a 32bpp bitmap? Is it perhaps a 24bpp bitmap?

Comment: @David: It *should* be... I tried it both with `CreateBitmap` as well as like in the `CreateDIBSection` example. There's obviously some kind of transparency going on here, the problem being that it also affects the font, not just the background. :\

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The link is broken, but available via internet wayback archive.